# Python: Apply code to an entire dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a column, col1, in a dataframe filled with values.

```
                                col1                
row1      [0.0, 6.33839991, 3.93961207, 5.27702178, 8.27702178, 6.44343, 5.668574]             
row2      [0.0, 5.93961207, 4.27702178, 4.12702178]
row3      [0.0, 6.44428501, 3.93961207, 8.27702178, 4.27121178]
```

Each row contains a series. I need a new column, col2 say, that returns a new series. This series starts at 0 and increments by 100 each time until this series matches the length of the original series.

**Expected output**

```
                            col1                               col2          
row1      [0.0, 6.3, 3.93, 5.27, 8.2, 6.4, 5.6]             [0,100,200,300,400,500,600]                       
row2      [0.0, 5.9, 4.2, 4.1]                              [0,100,200,300]
row3      [0.0, 6.4, 3.9, 8.2, 4.2]                         [0,100,200,300,400]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Lambda cannot contain an assignment

Comment: can you post the dataframe? and expected value?  its confusing what you want and based on  what

Comment: I have updated my question. I hope this is clear!

Comment: what you have duplicates in your list?

Comment: Duplicates do not matter. All I need is the total length of the list

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
def func(x):
    x['col2'] = np.arange(0, len(x['col1'])*100, 100)
    return x
df.apply(lambda x: func(x) , axis=1)
```

Comment: I edited the code to improve clarity of what I am trying to do

Comment: This code does not solve my problem, just to be clear

Comment: This was also my solution and it gets the required solution. However, I condensed it to a one-liner: `df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x : np.arange(0, len(x)*100, 100))`

Comment: Could you please mark this as a solution, if you seem so?

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you want the multiplication based on each unique string(factorized), for duplicated elements of the list , this will return duplicated results:

```
df['col2']=df.col1.transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]*100)
```

Or suggestion by @jezrael:

```
df.col1.apply(lambda x: np.arange(len(x))*100)


print(df)

                                                   col1  \
row1  [0.0, 6.33839991, 3.93961207, 5.27702178, 8.27...   
row2          [0.0, 5.93961207, 4.27702178, 4.12702178]   
row3  [0.0, 6.44428501, 3.93961207, 8.27702178, 4.27...   

                                   col2  
row1  [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]  
row2                 [0, 100, 200, 300]  
row3            [0, 100, 200, 300, 400]
```

Answer (score 2):

My propisition is:

```
df['col2'] = df.col1.transform(lambda x: [ i * 100 for i in range(len(x))])
```